# How do you use printf in x86 assembly in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, masm

Unhandled exception at 0x777745BA (ntdll.dll) in MASM1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014.
I'm using x86 assembly in visual studios 2017 and it keeps returning this error

I have included all of the libraries and installed windows 10 sdk. I am basically stumped as of why this is returning this error on line 21. It even opens a blank window and then immediately closes it returning the error.

```
            .586
            .MODEL FLAT
            .STACK 4096
            includelib libcmt.lib
            includelib libvcruntime.lib
            includelib libucrt.lib
            includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib
            EXTERN  printf:PROC
            EXTERN  scanf:PROC

            .DATA
                format BYTE "Enter a number", 0

            .CODE

            main PROC
                sub esp, 4
                push offset format
                call printf
                add esp, 4
                ret
            main ENDP
            END
```

I created a VS 2017 C++ project generating a Win32 console program. In the project properties / `Linker` / `Advanced` / `entry point` option I have set the entry point to `main`.

Comment: Yeah I've used ret already and that didn't fix anything

Comment: Then update your question with the version that has a `ret`; this version has an obvious huge bug.

Comment: Really, you still get `writing location 0x00000014` as the error with `ret`?  On which instruction?  Is it inside `printf`, or after main returns?

Comment: Just did sorry about that. Any other suggestions? I have been using the debugger this entire time trying to figure this out and can't seem to find the solution to the error

Comment: It specifically says line 19 which is when i add 4 back to esp.

Comment: That instruction doesn't write memory, it only modifies a register, so it's impossible for that instruction it to fault that way.  Use the disassembly view in your debugger to see actual instructions that run, not just the asm source.

Comment: The caller is responsible for cleaning up arguments to `printf`. So you need to `add esp, 8` before returning to clean up both the pushed `format` argument and to adjust for the `sub esp, 4`

Comment: I'm a bit surprised this assembles and links. I would have thought you would need `.MODEL FLAT, C` for it to properly link `main` since it really should resolve to `_main`. You say you are using Visual Studio 2017. Are you using custom assemble and link commands and if so what are the commands you are using to assemble and link? I have a suspicion you didn't create a VS2017 MSVC project with the IDE the normal way (by adding MASM as a build dependency) and then add an ASM file with this code.

Comment: I have a hunch that you have managed to circumvent running the _C_ runtime start up code (so `printf` won't run properly) and you have managed to force the entry point for your program to be main (with a command line option?). This is on top of the fact `add esp, 4` should be `add esp, 8`. I was able to reproduce your problem by forcing `main` to be the entry point by linking with the `/ENTRY` option. The other possibility is that what you are showing here for assembly code is not what you are actually using.

Comment: I can only recommend at a very minimum. Change `.MODEL FLAT` to `.MODEL FLAT, C` then change the `ADD ESP, 4` (after `printf`) to `ADD ESP, 8` and if you are linking with `/ENTRY` remove that option. That's what I recommend as long as you don't show your assembling and linking commands (and all the options).

Comment: Don't edit your question to give a solution. It is allowed and encouraged to create an answer to your own question.

Comment: Did you also by chance modify project properties / Microsoft Macro Assembler / Advanced / Calling Convention so that it was set to _Use C-style Calling Convention (/Gd) (/Gd)_?

Comment: @MichaelPetch which calling convention we use for self code no matter here. we can not change calling convention of external function (*printf*)

Comment: @RbMm : That's not why I asked the question. Changing the calling convention also changes whether MASM by default uses underscores or not. The code as posted doesn't use `.MODEL FLAT, C` so for this code to assemble and link without undefined references something external had to be set to override the default behaviour. For instance without changing the default behavior `EXTERN  printf:PROC` would have had to have been `EXTERN  _printf:PROC` and `main PROC` would have had to have been `_main PROC` etc.

Answer (score 6):

You have a `sub esp,4` and a `push` before the call, so to restore the stack pointer to point at the return address you need to **`add esp,8` before `ret`, instead of `add esp, 4`**

(`printf` is a varargs function so it does *not* pop its own args off the stack.  It uses a cdecl calling convention.)

**Or better, remove `sub esp,4`**.

32-bit Windows only maintains 4-byte stack alignment, so you don't need to do anything extra with ESP before a `push`/`call` to get the stack pointer re-aligned before a `call`.  And you're not using that 4 bytes you reserved for anything.

---

**Update: MichaelPetch observed that your program is probably crashing *inside* `printf`, because you called it without initializing libc.  Probably you're building your program with this function as the entry point, not called from the normal C startup code.**  (And that the Visual Studio debugger wrongly reports the crash as being on the line after the `call`, instead of where the crash actually happened.)

---

Your error message appears to still be from the first version of the question, where you left out the `ret`!  In that case, execution just falls of the end of `main` into whatever bytes are next, decoding them as instructions.  Probably zeros.

`00 00` decodes as `add [eax], al`, and `eax` holds 14 from the return value of printf.  (`printf` returns the number of characters printf, and your format string is 14 bytes long).

But the error message is about writing address `0x14`, which is decimal `20` (16 + 4), so my first guess doesn't quite add up.  **If you want to know, use a debugger to find the instruction that actually faults, and look at register values.**  You may have to use the disassembly view instead of asm source view, especially for the version where you fall off the end of `main`.

---

Probably you get no output on screen if `stdout` is line-buffered, and your printf format string doesn't end with a newline.  So the string is still sitting in the IO buffer when you crash.  (Although IIRC, `printf` on Windows isn't like that, and does `fflush()` the buffer even if it doesn't end with a newline.)

Use `puts` to print a fixed string (no `%` conversions) and append a newline.  i.e. `puts(x)` is like `printf("%s\n", x)`.

Comment: The debugger will erroneously show the error on line 21 (the `add esp, 4`) when in fact it actually occurred inside the `printf` call and the way I have reproduced it (right down to the value 0x00000014) is to prevent the _C_ runtime startup code from being executed (by making the entry point for the program `main`) rather than what is the default entry point in the _C_ runtime code. My opinion is the problem is more about how they are assembling and linking which is the info they don't provide :(

Comment: Sorry for not providing that my project build dependencies is set to masm check box. My linker advance entry point is set to main. The linker system is still console. I'm not sure what other information you want me to provide about what Im linking

Comment: @MikeD: Use `@username` to notify people you're replying to.  You're replying under my answer, so I get a ping, but MichaelPetch probably didn't.  That said, putting that info in your question would be a start.  Your normally want the entry point to be the CRT (C Runtime Startup) start code, so it can run the library init functions before calling your `main`.

Comment: @Michael Petch and Peter Cordes It was the entry point i removed the entry point main and thats what fixed it. Thank you guys for your time and info on this. Y'all have helped me a lot. Thank you again

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution proposed by the OP in an edit to their question:

I solved the problem by clearing the `linker`->`advanced`->`Entry point` option which I had set to `main` in the project properties.

As @PeterCordes suggests in his answer - the best solution to fix the stack related issue is to remove the `sub esp, 4`.